# return single value of first row when query return more than one row

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

Following table is my database tabel `question`.

[image]

when I pass `$ID=2` using this function,

```
function getFirstID($ID) {

        $checkQ = "SELECT * FROM tabel WHERE quiz_id = '$ID";
        $query = $this->db->query($checkQ);

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }            
}
```

the result will be,

[image]

I want to return `ID` of first row in result. so the output should be 4.

What is the modification that I should do in my function to get the expected output?

Comment: please provide expected output.for better understnding..

Comment: Your question isnt clear, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what mean `when quiz_id changes 1 or 2`

Comment: @user3002114 : not enough...

Comment: when you pass 2, how `num_rows` is 3? only 2 rows in your table. Read how to ask and make a better question

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza if i pass `1` to the function `getFirstID` the output should be `1`, if I pass `2` it should  return `3`

Comment: why will return 1? why will return 3? In your table sample count should be 3 and 2

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza its understandable now i guess

Comment: @SubinCPoonamgode its understandable now i guess.

Comment: what is the reason 4 over 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT `ID` FROM tabel WHERE quiz_id = '$ID ORDER BY `ID` LIMIT 1
```

Please try this query.

Comment: How this solve your question? Your output say for `$ID=2` you want two rows, also if you already filtering by `ID`, order by `ID` doesnt make anything

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ROWNUM`,`LIMIT`,`TOP`,`PERCENT` with this case,

1.) Deal with row numbers:

```
SELECT columnNames FROM Table_name
WHERE ROWNUM <= number;
```

2.) Can limit rows:

```
SELECT columnNames FROM Table_name LIMIT number;
```

3.) can select number of rows that you want from `TOP`

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Table_name;
```

4.) can select percentage from all number of result from this:

```
SELECT  TOP 25 PERCENT * FROM Table_name;
```

4th one is not better when compare with others,but we can use it.

Regarding to your case,we can assume these four reasons like this :

```
SELECT * FROM tabel WHERE quiz_id = '$ID AND ROWNUM <= 1;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM tabel WHERE quiz_id = '$ID AND LIMIT 1;
```

or

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tabel WHERE quiz_id = '$ID;
```

or

```
SELECT 50 PERCENT * FROM tabel WHERE quiz_id = '$ID;
```

Answer (score 2):

In CodeIgniter

```
 $this->db->select('ID');
 $this->db->from('tabel');
 $this->db->where('quiz_id',$ID);
 $this->db->order_by('ID');
 $q=$this->db->get();
 if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $q->row();   # Returns single row
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
```

Try this query